# Detect FB share dialog is ready

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, fbsdk

We need to display FB share dialog. It can be done with either FB.ui as:

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'iframe',
        href: '{{postUrl}}'
    });
```

or even using a link/REST.

I can add a second argument to FB.ui() as function(result){...}, and FB JavaScript SDK will invoke that as a callback after the dialog is closed [either with a share taking place, or without].

How could I detect that the dialog is displayed, not dismissed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can only be sure if someone shared something if you authorize the user with the `publish_actions` permission. In that case, you will get the Post ID in the callback, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#response

Keep in mind that you are not allowed to reward users in any way for sharing, or incentivize sharing. You will not get `publish_actions` approved by Facebook just for checking if the user shared something.

Edit 1: If you just want to know if the dialog is visible...well, it is visible when you call `FB.ui`, and it is not visible anymore then the callback gets called.

**Edit 2: I don´t see any use case for it (please do tell), but if you want to know if the dialog showed up (and did not get blocked by a popup blocker, for example), then i would say it is impossible to detect.**

Comment: Thank you for taking time to look at my post. Your answer is unrelated to my question, unfortunately. I know how to handle a callback with the result.

Comment: ok, you did not understand my answer...it is 100% related to your question. you want to know if the user really posted something with the share dialog, right? if not, please explain.

Comment: maybe, i did not. i wish, you would answered my question, though.

Comment: so what exactly is your question then? instead of commenting "you did not answer", why not explain?

Comment: if your only question is to know if "the dialog is displayed"...well, if you call FB.ui, it is visible. it´s as simple as that.

Comment: now that you understood the question, i appreciate your time even more. :)

Comment: added it to my answer. still unclear what you want to achieve, though.

Comment: it is too bad that you do not realize that requests to facebook are async and dialog does not just appear by itself. thank you for trying. :)

Comment: you could have been a lot more specific in your question. after so many comments with a weird and somehow negative tone, i finally know what you mean (i guess).... that´s really not how stackoverflow works. you ask clear questions, you get clear answers. not sure why you would downvote my answer either, i will add another edit. see the bold text. if you believe that someone did not understand your question, EXPLAIN it. just pointing out the obvious, please let us continue this on a more professional level instead.